Close problem popup in vscode programmatically
I switched the keybind in Visual Studio Code to go to the next problem (previously fn+F8) to my unused key F19 like this (keybindings.json):
  {
    "key": "f19",
    "when": "editorFocus",
    "command": "runCommands",
    "args": {
      "commands": [
        "editor.action.marker.nextInFiles"
      ]
    }
  }

My goal is to only set my cursor to the next problem, but this problem popup allways shows up and I'm only able to close it by clicking the X or pressing escape - that got annyoing rather quickly.
I've searched a lot but haven't been able to find anything usefull.
This is the popup im talking about:
VS Code Problem Popup
I imagine something like editor.action.marker.closePopup (this doesn't exist sadly).
Or maybe a way to invoke an Escape key press.
Is there anything that might help me?
